# EasyApache 4 ea-tomcat85 instance is not restarting

Tags: cpanel, tomcat8, easyapache-4

I had this issue for several days. I have a Linux Centos server working with CPanel and I use EasyApache 4 with Tomcat 8.5 for my Java Web applications. Each CPanel user has 1 instance of Tomcat so if I made changes in my .java or .class files, I need to restart the Tomcat instance.

The problem is that Tomcat 8.5 (ea-tomcat85) is not restarting. Previously there are working well... I use this command to restart it: "ubic restart ea-tomcat85" but it not works.

I try stopping it and start(When I use start, trows "is already running") I again and nothing. ¿What is happening?

PD: I already check the logs and they don't show anything according the instance service